# How to declare Content-type so that browsers recognize a page is an Atom/RSS feed?

Tags: browser, rss, atom-feed

I'm sending the HTTP header **"Content-type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8"** in my Atom 2.0 feed right now (using the header() function in PHP).

Whenever I open the URL in Chrome or Konqueror, it will just show text.
If I change that to **application/xml**, Chrome will display an XML tree and Konqueror will still display that as text.

Since I have an Agregator on my computer, shouldn't that xml be opened with it?
And if not, since these standards have more than 10 years, shouldn't these browser at least put a button on top of the page to invite downloading an Agregator?

Because of these 2 reasons I guess I'm not using the proper content-type. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Content-Type is not the only problem... browsers are to blame mostly, because they "forgot" how to handle RSS/Atom at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct Content-Type for an Atom feed ([application/atom+xml](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/atom+xml)). However, Chromium does not handle it correctly ([Issue 104358: RSS feeds are not parsed correctly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104358)).

One possible workaround for Chromium's bug is to use a more general type (e.g., `application/xml`). Alternatively, stick with the correct type and accept that users who have chosen that browser will get a more confusing experience.